# wordpress(woocomerce) how to add button to header

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, header, wordpress-theming

I am using theme named storefront on wordpress(woocommrece) and I need to add simple button to header.

I tried adding it in code (didn't work well), but only in header.php because I couldn't found hooks.

Comment: Where in header? what is this button? Your question is just unclear actually and very vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find header.php of that theme then try find class 
*header-menu-signup header-menu-button wccom-component-button*

That class should contain header button by default so you can modify it by your needs. Best of luck.